# Distributing Xamarin Forms App via Visual Studio App Center

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-app-center

I want to share an enterprise Xamarin Forms app with some users in the company for beta testing. These are iPhone users. I understand that the app can be shared via a link that is sent in an email.

Do the beta users need to run some wrapper app to run my app or would the app just work as a normal iOS app?

Comment: App Center will distribute your app's `.ipa` by resigning it based upon your Apple Developer Id. So if you are `ad-hoc` distributing a beta, App Center does not currently perform automatic device provisioning so you need the UUIDs of the devices that you will be adding to your distribution groups.

Comment: Unless you are utilizing the other App Center services, I *personally* find Apple's TestFlight way easier to publish to a beta app as the device's are automatically provisioned with your developer Id provisioning profile and also course you can publish it via `fastline` (Pilot/Deploy) which Xamarin fully supports and then just email an install url link to your testers

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.